# When is an earth ground necessary?

Tags: ground

For large appliances I usually see a 3-prong plug while smaller electronics will use a 2 prong wall wart with a DC barrel. When designing electronics, how do you know if you'll need an earth ground? Are the two prong designs inherently more dangerous?

Comment: Devices using just live and neutral are often (always?) double insulated meaning that any high voltage stuff is insulated within the case the electronics are in.

Answer (score 2):

The regulations are described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appliance_classes . Actual implementation varies by country - all UK sockets have 3 pins for example.

Small appliances can use low-current low-voltage DC. All the safety isolation is in the wall wart; it's not possible for the appliance itself to fail in a way that gives the user an electric shock.

Larger appliances either have a power supply built in or use mains directly (drills, white goods, lamps, etc). These must either be double-insulated or have an earth ground.